# launch chrome from a shortcut/file also need specific logo for that file

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I want to launch chrome with specific URL using a short cut/file.
I also want that files logo to be set using an `.ico` file i have.

I have written a `.bat` file with following code in it.

```
start chrome "www.google.com"
```

now the problem is, i can not change icon of that batch file.

can anyone please guide me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a batch file for this. It's easier to just create a shortcut to Chrome and set your `.ico` file as the icon. If you can be sure that you can launch Chrome from the command line, then You probably want the target of the shortcut to be something like

`C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "start chrome http://www.my-site.com"`

Comment: i will be placing it on different machines where chrome's actual path will not be known what to do?

Comment: Just create the shortcut to the command line, and then pass in the same thing as your `.bat` file contains.

Comment: how to create that? can you please help with syntax? i am totally new to this!

Comment: Create a shortcut of Chrome, and then right click on it and click Properties, and then copy the line from my answer and paste it in the Target line in the Properties window. Then click Change Icon, and set it to your icon.

Comment: ok, i have done that and it worked, just a small query, in "Start in" option it has value "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application", will that be the same in all machines? being it XP, WIN7 any windows machine 32, 64 bit?

Comment: You can delete the Start In value. Chrome will then just "start in" whichever folder it lives.